# Convert words in char array to a line with single space

Tags: c, arrays

Convert the given `char *input[]` to a line with single space

**Inputs**:

```
int n =3;
char *result;
char *input[]= {"one", "two", "three" };
result = convertToLine(n, input)
```

**Code**

```
char *convertToLine(int n, char *input[]) {
    int size = n* 2;
    char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);        
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i <size){
        string[i] = *input[k];         
        string[i+1] = ' ';
        i++;
        k++;
     }
   string[n] = '\0';
   return string;
}
```

**My Output:**
Null

**Expected Output**:

```
result = "one two three"
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: the question is "why that code doesn't work" ^^

Comment: Well, n = 3 => size = 6. `string` will be a char array with size 6. There would be more than 6 characters into the final array, that's for sure. (as an initial mistake).

Comment: A debugger would be helpful in finding out why your program acts like it does.  If you don't know how to use a debugger yet, this looks like a good program to use as you learn the basics.

Comment: @Sanjana In C you don't have strings, you have arrays of chars. `string[i] = *input[k];  ` won't copy the kth string from input inside your "string", it would copy only one letter. Also, `string` has space for only 6 characters, where you need 3 + 3 + 5 + 2 (from spaces) + 1 (from NULL terminator) = 13. ` without using library functions` => you will also need a function to get the length of each word, or otherwise you'll have to realloc your buffer a lot of times.

Comment: `sizeof(char)*size` allocated memory for 3 characters. You need two spaces, zero termination character and the characters in stirngs. `sizeof(char) * (strlen(input[0]) + strlen(input[1]) + strlen(input[2]) + 3));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, your problem is you cannot assign strings, e.g.

```
string[i] = *input[k];
```

Above, you are attempting to assign the 1st characters of the k<sup>th</sup> pointer to `string[i]` which will read beyond the end of `input`. It is equivalent to:

```
*(input[k] + 0)
```

or

```
input[k][0]
```

See: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Instead you need to either call `strcpy` or simply use an additional loop to copy each of the desired characters, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertToLine (size_t n, char *input[])
{
    size_t  ndx = 0,        /* string index */
            len = 0;        /* length of combined strings */
    char *string = NULL;    /* pointer to string */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  /* length of all in input */
        len += strlen (input[i]);

    string = malloc (len + n);      /* allocate len + n-1 space + 1 */
    if (!string) {                  /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc-string");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {        /* for each string */
        if (i)                              /* if not 1st */
            string[ndx++] = ' ';            /* add space */
        for (int j = 0; input[i][j]; j++)   /* copy input string */
            string[ndx++] = input[i][j];
    }
    string[ndx] = '\0';     /* nul-terminate */
    return string;
}
```

Adding a short example with your `input` you would have:

```
int main (void) {
    char *input[]= {"one", "two", "three" },
        *result = NULL;
    size_t n = sizeof input / sizeof *input;

    result = convertToLine (n, input);
    if (result) {
        printf ("result: '%s'\n", result);
        free (result);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_combind
result: 'one two three'
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several errors in your code

> int size = n* 2;
>   char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

The needed *size* must be the final size, so the sum of the length of the string to merge more the place for the spaces and final null character. `n *2` is just the double of the number of strings, this is not the same

> string[i] = *input[k];

that doesn't not copy the string but only its first character

you can do that :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertToLine(int n, char *input[]) {
  /* compute the needed size,
     of course can also use malloc then realloc to avoid that */
  int size = 0;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    size += strlen(input[i]) + 1;

  /* copy the strings */
  char * string = (char*)malloc(size); /* sizeof(char) is 1 by definition */
  char * p = string;

  for (i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    strcpy(p, input[i]);
    p += strlen(p);
    *p++ = ' ';
  }
  p[-1] = 0;

  return string;
}


int main()
{
  char *input[]= {"one", "two", "three" };
  char * result = convertToLine(3, input);
  puts(result);

  free(result);
}
```

Execution:

```
one two three
```

Execution under valgrind:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==14749== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14749== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14749== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14749== Command: ./a.out
==14749== 
one two three
==14749== 
==14749== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14749==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14749==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,038 bytes allocated
==14749== 
==14749== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14749== 
==14749== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14749== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase i by 2 each iteration because if you increase it by 1 you will keep overwriting the spaces and end up copying the words, and eventually reading uninitialized memory. Good luck mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char *arr_to_sentece(char **arr, size_t len)
{
    size_t mems = 0;
    char *sentence, *saveds; 

    for(size_t index = 0; index < len; index++)
        mems += strlen(arr[index]);
    mems += len - 1;
    sentence = malloc(mems + 1);
    if(sentence)
    {
        size_t wlen;

        saveds = sentence;
        while(len--)
        {
            wlen = strlen(*arr);

            strcpy(sentence, *arr++);
            sentence[wlen] = ' ';
            sentence += wlen + 1;
        }
        *sentence = 0;
    }
    return saveds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and make a some changes, some of the previous answer works fine but if you want to achieve this without using any third lib functions this is my way to do it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getWordLength(const char input[]) {
    int cont = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //count the characters of the word, the last defining char always is '\0'
    while (input[i] != '\0') {
        cont++;
        i++;
    }
    return cont;
}

int getSentenceLength(int n, const char *input[]) {
    int sentenceLength = 0;
    //add the word length to the total sentence length
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sentenceLength += getWordLength(input[i]);
    }
    //add the spaces length
    sentenceLength += n;
    return sentenceLength;
}

void addWordToSentence(char* string, const char input[]) {
    int length = getWordLength(input); //get the word length

    //add the word to tha final sentence char by char
    int i = 0;
    int j = getWordLength(string);
    for ( ; i < length; i++, j++) {
        string[j] = input[i];
    }

    //add one space after the added word
    string[j] = ' ';
}

void cleanString(char* string, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        string[i] = '\0';
    }
}

char *convertToLine(int n, const char *input[]) {
    //get the total size
    int size = getSentenceLength(n, input);
    char* string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

    //clean the string with '\0'
    cleanString(string, size);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        addWordToSentence(string, input[i]);
        i++;
    }

    string[size - 1] = '\0';
    return string;
}

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    char *result;
    const char *input[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    result = convertToLine(n, input);
    cout << result;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Tested and working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
char *convertToLine(int size, char *input[]) {

   char *string = NULL;
   for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
   {

        int size_to_allocate = string != NULL ? strlen(string)+ strlen(input[i]) +2 : strlen(input[i]) +2;
        string = (char*)realloc(string, sizeof(char) * size_to_allocate);
        strcat(string, input[i]);
        if(i< size -1)strcat(string, " ");
   }
   return string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use realloc to reallocate momory when needed and concatenate words needed.

```
    char *convertToLine(int size, char *input[]) {

   char *string = NULL;
   for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
   {
        int size_to_allocate = string != NULL ? strlen(string)+ strlen(input[i]) : strlen(input[i]);
        string = (char*)realloc(string, sizeof(char) * size_to_allocate);
        strcat(string, input[i]);
        if(i< size -1)strcat(string, " ");
   }
   return string;
}
```

Comment: sorry but that code doesn't work at all, the realloc size if not the right one

Comment: thanks bruno, fortunatly it is working I have no idea how., but I realized my mistake

Comment: <pre>char *convertToLine(int size, char *input[]) {

   char *string = NULL;
   for(int i =0; i&lt;size; i++)
   {
        int size_to_allocate = string != NULL ? strlen(string)+ strlen(input[i]) : strlen(input[i]);
        string = (char*)realloc(string, sizeof(char) * size_to_allocate);
        strcat(string, input[i]);
        if(i&lt; size -1)strcat(string, &quot; &quot;);
   }
   return string;
}
</pre>

Comment: Your new version is still wrong, you missed one char. I encourage you to look at _valgrind_ to check your memory accesses / leaks, hopping you can use it in station

Comment: thanks. yes! you are right. I will check valgrind